# Subset a pandas dataframe based on column value using chain rule

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date

Let say I have below code

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['2010-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2012-01-01', '2013-01-01'], 'B' : [1,2,3,4]})


start = pd.to_datetime('2011Q1').to_period('Q').start_time
end = pd.to_datetime('2012Q1').to_period('Q').start_time

dat['A1'] = pd.to_datetime(dat['A'])
dat1 = dat[dat['A1'].between(start, end)]
```

As you can see, in the second last line I am creating a new column `A1` with type `date` and in the last line, I am subsetting based in that newly created column

I am looking for some way how can I use `chain rule` to perform above 2 calculations using a single line of code?

Any pointer will be very helpful

Comment: Try `dat.assign(A1=pd.to_datetime(dat['A1']).query('@start <= A1 <= @end')` will test later on phone now.

Comment: Thanks. It works. If you can answer this, I will accept and close

Comment: Great.  Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use `assign` and `query` like this:

```
dat.assign(A1=pd.to_datetime(dat['A'])).query('@start <= A1 <= @end')
```

Output:

```
            A  B         A1
1  2011-01-01  2 2011-01-01
2  2012-01-01  3 2012-01-01
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) to apply chainable functions that expect DataFrames.

```py
out = dat.assign(A1=pd.to_datetime(dat['A'])).pipe(lambda df: df[df['A1'].between(start, end)])
```

```
print(out)

            A  B         A1
1  2011-01-01  2 2011-01-01
2  2012-01-01  3 2012-01-01
```